# Ejecutable .Jar no ejecuta correctamente todos los metodos

Tags: java, apache

Al correr el ejecutable .jar de el sistema realizado, a la hora de ejecutar un método que incluye el proceso de generar un archivo excel, no genera absolutamente nada, pero cuando lo corro en netbeans si lo genera, no saben a que se debe??
Leí que podria ser porque no se pasan las librerias al ejecutable? cualquier consejo seria de gran ayuda, de antemano muchas gracias...

Comment: Cuando se genera el ejecutable las librerías se agregan al JAR, pero si haces uso de estas deben estar incluidas en el classpath que dice donde se encuentran las librerías que utiliza tu programa para funcionar. Igual nos falta mas información para responder ya que puede ser por cualquier motivo. Por dar una idea puedes intentar ejecutar el JAR desde la linea de comandos y reproducir los pasos hasta donde dices que no funciona para ver si lanza algún error que en el IDE no.

Comment: Perfecto, lo intentare de la forma como comentas, muchas gracias